# Help with proof about solvability of linear diophantine equation.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

**Prove:**
If $a_1,...,a_n,c \in \mathbb Z,n \in \mathbb N$ then the equation $$a_1x_1+a_2x_2+\dots+a_nx_n=c$$
has integer solutions iff $\gcd(a_1,...,a_n)|c$.

---

*Proof:*

($k=1,...,n$)

$\Longrightarrow$ As $\gcd(a_1,...,a_n)$ divides all $a_k$, it also divides all their linear combinations.

This is the part I'm not sure about: $\Longleftarrow$

Let c be a multiple of $\gcd(a_1,...,a_n)$, then $\exists z\in \mathbb Z$ such that $c=z\cdot \gcd(a_1,...,a_n)$. As there  $\exists x'_k:$

$$a_1x'_1+a_2x'_2+\dots+a_nx'_n=\gcd(a_1,...,a_n),$$

we can simply multiply by z and recieve

$$a_1x'_1z+a_2x'_2z+\dots+a_nx'_nz=c,$$

where $x'_kz$ are the new solutions. Given, that this is correct so far:
Do I have to show that, if c is not divisible by $\gcd(a_k)$, the equation has no integer solutions?

Comment: The setup of your proof seems good to me. You do not need to show that if $c$ is not divisible by $\gcd(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$, the equation has no integer solutions. This is the contrapositive of '$\Rightarrow$', which you have already proven.

Comment: You may need to prove (by induction) the result you asserted about representing the gcd as a linear combination. The result has undoubtedly already been proved in your course for the case $n=2$. But it takes some work to extend to $n$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Given that there are x,y such that $ax+by=\gcd(a,b)$, then there are also x,y such that $ax+by=\gcd(a,b) \cdot m$.  
To show that after expanding to $ax+by+cz$ it again equals to $\gcd(a,b,c),$ replace the first two:  $$\gcd(a,b)*m+cz=\gcd(a,b,c),$$
And because of the property $\gcd(\gcd(a,b),c)=\gcd(a,b,c),$ I can add arbitrarily many elements that way, right?

Comment: Yes, you have in essence given the induction step. It does require the observation that $\gcd(\gcd(a_1,\dots,a_k),a_{k+1})=\gcd(a_1,\dots,a_{k+1})$.